# Is $f(z) =\sqrt{z}$ anywhere for $z$ complex?

Tags: complex-analysis

I say $f(z)=\sqrt{z}$ is not analytic because it is not differentiable at $(0,0)$. $f'(z) = \lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{\sqrt{z+h} - \sqrt{h}}{z-h} = \frac{\sqrt{z}}{z} = \infty$. The one sided limit as $h$ approached along the real axis is infinite. Hence $f$ is not differentiable.

Agree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not analytic on the entire plane, but it is when defined on some subsets of the plane, for example the complement of the non-positive real axis.

Comment: How can that be possible if the function is not differentiable?

Comment: @complolost The non-differentiability lies outside the domain . . .

Comment: It is differentiable anywhere other than 0.

Comment: Ah, of course. Thank you both.

Answer (score 0):

$$f(z)=\sqrt{z}=\sqrt{r}(cos(\frac{\theta}{2})+isin(\frac{\theta}{2})).$$ Clearly $f$ is not continuous on $(-\infty,0]$ i.e. on negative real axis as its imaginary part is on continuous on negative real axis. Therefore $f$ is not differentiable and hence not analytic at zero.